# Is this a correct Factory Method implementation?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm learning about design pattern and I tried to implement a Factory Method example, based on the GoF book.

Can I say that this is a correct implementation of it ? If not I will be glad to find out what are the pitfalls.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class Widget {
public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class Win7Widget : public Widget {
public:
    void draw() { cout << "Win 7 widget" << endl; }
};

class Win8Widget : public Widget {
public:
    void draw() { cout << "Win 8 widget" << endl; }
};


class Factory {
public:
    virtual Widget* Create() = 0;
    virtual ~Factory() {}
};

class Win7Factory: public Factory {
public:
    Widget* Create() { return new Win7Widget; }
};

class Win8Factory: public Factory {
public:
    Widget* Create() { return new Win8Widget; }
};


int main()
{
    unique_ptr<Factory> win7fact(new Win7Factory);
    unique_ptr<Factory> win8fact(new Win8Factory);

    vector<Widget*> widgets;
    widgets.push_back(win7fact->Create());
    widgets.push_back(win8fact->Create());

    for(const auto& f : widgets)
    {
        f->draw();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5121930/14065

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall, it is pretty good.

The one thing you should improve is returning a smart pointer from the factory method. The way it is now, returning a raw pointer, it is up to the caller to decide how the memory management of the object is to be done. This is sub-optimal, as it leaves room for error. In your example, the widgets will leak, as nobody is explicitly owning that memory. So `Create()` should return either a shared or unique pointer. Unique seems more fit for this case:

```
virtual std::unique_ptr<Widget> Create() = 0;
```

Or use a type alias to make the code less verbose:

```
using WidgetPtr = std::unique_ptr<Widget>;
```

---

Avoid `using namespace std;`. It is not that much more typing, and there are [gains to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

---

The destructor of `Factory` is empty, so you should make it a default (C++11 feature):

```
virtual ~Factory() = default;
```

---

No need to explicitly `return 0` from `main()`. The compiler adds it automatically for main if omitted.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use dynamic allocation if automatic objects will do:

```
unique_ptr<Factory> win7fact(new Win7Factory);
unique_ptr<Factory> win8fact(new Win8Factory);
```

Should be:

```
Win7Factory win7fact;
Win8Factory win8fact;
```